# Searching Excel

Tags: python, excel, python-2.7, xlrd

I have a script that searches each row of an Excel document until it finds an empty row. My issue is i cant get it to move down the rows without calling the function the correct amount of times to reach an empty row (which defeats the purpose of the script). When I tried to make the Excel search function loop within itself I keep getting an IndexError. I tried to create another function outside the original function based on boolean values of global variables but had the same issues (hence the incomplete and the empty variables)  Could someone please help me figure out what I'm doing wrong?

```
import xlrd
workbook = xlrd.open_workbook( 'example.xls' )
sheet_names = workbook.sheet_names()

global incomplete
global empty
global nextrow
global counter
incomplete = False
empty = False
counter = 0
def excelreader():
    for sheet_name in sheet_names:
      sheet = workbook.sheet_by_name( 'A Test Sheet')    
      global counter
      try:
          row_values = sheet.row_values(counter)
          counter += 1
          if '' in row_values:
              global incomplete
              incomplete = True
              print incomplete
      except IndexError:
          print'IndexError'




def exceliterator():
    if incomplete is False:
        excelreader()

excelreader()
excelreader()
excelreader()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You does not need exception or function definition to exit from loop. Simplest way: keyword `break`:

```
import xlrd
workbook = xlrd.open_workbook( 'test.xls' )
sheet_names = workbook.sheet_names()

incomplete_line = False

for sheet_name in sheet_names:
    sheet = workbook.sheet_by_name(sheet_name)
    for row_idx in range(0, sheet.nrows):
        row_values = sheet.row_values(row_idx)
        if '' in row_values:
            print "Incomplete line in sheet", sheet_name, "at line", row_idx+1
            incomplete_line = True
            break
    if incomplete_line:
        break
```